# Correct Method of Utilizing nohup in Batch Process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, nohup

What would be the best method of using nohup in a batch script with multiple calls inside the script.

For example, I have a script called filebuilder.sh and it contains something like:

```
/usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileA
/usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileB
/usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileC
```

What I want to do is make ensure that if I run my script, it will continue even if my SSH session is terminated. Should I just call the script like so:

```
nohup filebuilder.sh
```

or place nohup before every entry in the file such as:

```
nohup /usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileA
nohup /usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileB
nohup /usr/bin/python buildFile.py fileC
```

or Both? If I place it only on the script, is it possible that one of the python calls could still fail on a termination signal? What is the best practice and which solution will accomplish my requirements? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting `nohup` on each line is not the answer.  If you do that, and the session is terminated, the currently-running program will run to completion, but then the script will terminate without finishing.  `nohup filebuilder.sh` will work, but then you have to remember to do it every time.  A couple of solutions:

1. Write `filebuilder.sh` to say

```
    exec nohup name_of_the_real_filebuilder.sh
```

2. Put

```
    trap "" 1
```

at the beginning of your script.  (1 is the numeric value of the “hangup” signal.)

Comment: thanks for the response. Is that a do both situation or an either or situation for your solutions?

Comment: @Dave: Either (1) or (2).